# Which SharePoint API to use JSOM or REST?

Tags: sharepoint, office-js, office-addins, sharepoint-jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I am a SharePoint novice and need help to determine which api set to use. I have given task to  develop an outlook web add-in which will be side loaded to client's computer. This add-in will perform search on SharePoint lists and access content types and allow to move emails to SharePoint.

I have two options from what [Choose the right API set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/choose-the-right-api-set-in-sharepoint) tells me, REST OR JSOM.
It says to use JSOM but I am favoring little towards using REST.

My Concerns using REST is if it supports

1. External content types. I used Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.Entity in .NET CSOM?
2. Managed Meta Data/TaxonomyFieldTypes?

Are there any benefits of using one on another?

Really appreciate any comments or suggestions :)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,rest support both of them.

rest update managed matadata:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4758